# How the PrincipalContext works

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I need to let users bind there accounts to the Active Directory. This means that admin needs a GUI where he/she can write a Active Directory account like this : MyDomain\MyName and then get a validation if the users exists before save.

Im using this code to validate the name :

```
public static bool CheckActiveDirectoryAccount(string account)
        {

            string ADServer = null;
            string ADDomain = null;
            string ADUserName = null;
            string ADUserPassword = null;

            SetADSettings(out ADServer, out ADDomain, out ADUserName, out ADUserPassword);

            using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServer, ADUserName, ADUserPassword))
            {
                using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, account))
                {
                    if(user != null)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem with this code is that there seems to be no way to check the user for a specific domain? Instead I have to input the server, if I try to input the domain instead there will be exception(Server not found).

How do I let the admin enter domain and username of a AD account and then check it against the AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this :

```
public static string CheckActiveDirectoryAccount(string account)
        {
            UserPrincipal user;
            PrincipalContext context;
            List<string> userPrincipalNameList;
            string ADServer = null;
            string ADUserName = null;
            string ADUserPassword = null;

            string userAccount;

            account = account.ToLower();
            GetADSettings(out ADServer, out ADUserName, out ADUserPassword);

            if (ADUserName.Length > 0)
                context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServer, null,  ADUserName, ADUserPassword);
            else
                context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServer);

            using (context)
            {
                if((user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, account)) == null)
                {
                    if(account.Contains("\\"))
                    {
                        userPrincipalNameList = user.UserPrincipalName.Split('\\').ToList();

                        if (userPrincipalNameList.Count > 0)
                            user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userPrincipalNameList[0]);
                    }
                }

                if (user != null)
                {
                    using (user)
                    {
                        userPrincipalNameList = user.UserPrincipalName.Split('@').ToList();

                        userAccount = userPrincipalNameList.First();

                        if (userPrincipalNameList.Count > 1)
                            userAccount = userPrincipalNameList.Last() + "\\" + userAccount;

                        if (user != null)
                            return userAccount.ToLower();
                    }
                }
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to pass the domain into the principalcontext without issue, I'm not passing in the server. I would expect this to work for you.

```
public static bool CheckActiveDirectoryAccount(string account, string domain)
{
    using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
    {
        // Find a user
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, account);

        if (user == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

I have noticed poor performance when passing in the NetBIOS domain name, though it does work. As a result I pass in the DNS domain name whenever possible.

Comment: What do you mean with DNS domain? How does your domain look like? My is just MyDomain.local.

Comment: When I enter my domain(MyDomain or MyDomain.local) I will get : A first chance exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll

Additional information: The server could not be contacted.